# Could I use tesseract.js to recognize text in a discord channel in a browser?

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract.js

I'm trying to process messages/text from a discord channel on a server I'm a part of. The owners don't allow discord bots (for valid reasons, it's a subscription service). I'd still like to be able to parse the messages and respond to them with code. Assuming this would have to be in a browser. I looked into firefox extensions, but it looks like they have some kind of Content Security Policy to prevent the extension background script from loading or running. Again, makes sense. I'm not trying to do anything nefarious. Eventually just do some automated responses to the messages, to automate what I do manually to respond.

I thought about OCR and recently discovered tesseract.js. At a quick glance, it looks like it's focused on images, but there are chrome and firefox extensions, and another sub-project that processes videos. Looks like the extensions still focus on images.

Any other ideas?

Sorry if this is too broad for STO. I tried posting the same to the javascript subreddit and it got removed. Not sure if it's appropriate for [AskJS] there or not. Seemed to be kind of in between that and here.